# MediaWiki share my custom skin "myskin"

Tags: mediawiki

I have a custom skin on a private instance of MediaWiki. I would like other logged in users to be able to preview my custom skin.

Using Preferences > Appearance > Myskin Preview results in the following URL:
https://url.com/index.php?title=Page_name&useskin=myskin

I assumed other users can preview my custom skin using something like:
https://url.com/index.php?title=Page_name&useskin=**User:name/myskin** 
But that didn't work.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well if it is YOUR private instance of the wiki, you could just change the skin via `$wgDefaultSkin`. Everyone could see it then. What is it, that you want to accomplish? Sorry: cannot comment yet. This is no answer.

Comment: i'm trying to get other users feedback on potential css changes prior to implementing them wiki wide.